# Design an efficient algorithm to find the post-office location minimizing the average distance

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Let x1< x2 < . . . < xn be real numbers representing coordinates of n villages located along a straight road. A post office needs to be built in one of these villages.
a)  Design an efficient algorithm to find the post-office location minimizing the average distance between the villages and the post office.

I have written this algorthm can anyone check if it's correct?

```
Algorithm PostOffice(P)

    m <- (x1+xn) / 2
    i <- 1
    while xi < m do
        i <- i+1
    if xi - x1 < xn - xi-1
        return xi
    else return xi-1
```

Comment: Does the post office have to be in one of the villages?

Answer (score 2):

If we must return to post office in **each visit** the optimal location can be found like following approach. If there is odd number of points the optimum location is middle point in sorted order. Otherwise all points between two points which are in middle in sorted order of input are optimal. This problem known as 1-median problem.

**PS:** I think this is not what the problem asks but if postman start from post office and goes throw cities and came back to the post office at last, every point between min and max point is optimal. The cost is equal to `2*(X_max - X_min)`